# mongo database doesn't show up in command line

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I don't understand why my mongo db isn't showing up when I run "show databases" in the command line.  I see other mongo db's I created in the past, but not the current one.  Here is my code: (using mongoose ORM):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fuelTracker');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var fuelSchema = new Schema({
  time : { type : Date, default: Date.now },
  miles : Number,
  gallons: Number
});

var FuelStop = mongoose.model('FuelStop', fuelSchema);

module.exports = FuelStop;
```

And where I'm attempting a basic model.save operation:

```
  app.post('/', function (req, res ) {
  results = req.body;
  var fuelStop = new FuelStop (results)
  fuelStop.save(function() {
    console.log('record saved to monogoDB');
  });
})
```

Any clue as to why my 'fuelTracker' database doesn't appear in the command line when I run 'show databases' within mongo?

THANK YOU!!

Comment: Does your database have any collections at this point?

Answer (score 0):

did you try `show dbs`? `show databases` print all databases *available*, see the doc here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't get created until you insert data into a collection in the database.

I tested your code by creating and running a script to seed the fuelTracker database with example JSON data. I then ran `show databases` and was able to see fuelTracker listed.

If you would like to try this, in a new file `seed.js`:

```
const db = require('./fileName.js');
const fs = require('fs');

let fuelData = fs.readFileSync('./data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});

let jsonFuel = JSON.parse(fuelData);

db.remove({}, () => {
  console.log('Successfully removed fuel data');
  db.collection.insert(jsonFuel, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`error inserting data: ${err}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Fuel data was stored: ${docs}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Then create example data in `data.json`:

```
[
  {
    "time":"04/18/2018",
    "miles":"28",
    "gallons":"30"
  }
]
```

Then run your seed file and your database should hopefully be showing up.